# Submitting Job Arguments to Spark Job in Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

Trying to run [Spark-Wiki-Parser](https://github.com/nielsenbe/Spark-Wiki-Parser) on a GCP Dataproc cluster. The code takes in two arguments "dumpfile" and "destloc". When I submit the following I get a `[scallop] Error: Excess arguments provided: 'gs://enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 gs://output_dir/'`.

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --project $CLUSTER_PROJECT \
--class 'com.github.nielsenbe.sparkwikiparser.wikipedia.sparkdbbuild.DatabaseBuildMain' \
--properties=^#^spark.jars.packages='com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.5.0,com.github.nielsenbe:spark-wiki-parser_2.11:1.0' \
--region=$CLUSTER_REGION \
-- 'gs://enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2' 'gs://output_dir/'
```

How do I get the code to recognize the input arguments?

Comment: Could you share your code you use to parse the input arguments?

Answer (score 2):

I spent probably 8 hours figuring this out, but figured I'd dump the solution here since it had not been shared yet.

The gcloud CLI separates the dataproc parameters from the class arguments by -- as noted by another user.  However, Scallop also requires a -- prior to each named argument.  Your cli should look something like this.

gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --project $CLUSTER_PROJECT
--class 'com.github.nielsenbe.sparkwikiparser.wikipedia.sparkdbbuild.DatabaseBuildMain' 
--properties=^#^spark.jars.packages='com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.5.0,com.github.nielsenbe:spark-wiki-parser_2.11:1.0' 
--region=$CLUSTER_REGION 
-- --dumpfile'gs://enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2' --destloc 'gs://output_dir/'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Scala class needs dumpfile and destloc as args. 
Could you run following command instead and try if it works?

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --project $CLUSTER_PROJECT \
--class 'com.github.nielsenbe.sparkwikiparser.wikipedia.sparkdbbuild.DatabaseBuildMain' \
--properties=^#^spark.jars.packages='com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.5.0,com.github.nielsenbe:spark-wiki-parser_2.11:1.0' \
--region=$CLUSTER_REGION \
-- dumpfile gs://enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 destloc gs://output_dir/
```